# Please fix Stack Overflow for Teams moderation tools hyperlinks to point to the team's sections instead of the public site

Tags: bug, moderation, stack-overflow-for-teams, hyperlinks

I can access my private team moderation tools using the following link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team}/tools
```

However, all the links there are pointing to the public site:

[image: moderation tools links]

- [New answers to old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions)
- [Anonymous and low rep post feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback)
- [Site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics)

These are not the all the links, but they are particularly useful for a private team moderator (all others are not applicable for the private team).